# Cálculos de edad para los bebes

Tags: php, mysql

Un saludo a todos, tengo una fecha de nacimiento guardada en una base de datos en donde se debe de mostrar la edad de un usuario algo muy fácil utilizando `TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,nacimiento_vecino,CURDATE()) AS edad` el cual muestra los años que el usuario posee pero ahora tengo una cuestión que pasa cuando es un bebe que tiene días y meses de nacido ya que utilizar `TIMESTAMPDIFF` me muestra 0, porque tiene poco días de nacimiento.

¿Me recomendaría alguna otra forma cuando se presenta el cálculo de edad de los bebes?

Gracias por su colaboración

Comment: Si sacas la diferencia en dias en lugar de en años, puedes dividir los dias de diferencia entre 30 para sacar los meses. El resto de esa división lo divides a su vez entre 7 y te dará las semanas. El resto de esa división te dará los días. Por ejemplo si la diferencia entre el nacimiento y el dia de hoy son 143 días. el bebé tendrá: 143 / 30 = 4 meses. (143 % 30) / 7 = 3 semanas. (143 % 30) % 7 = 2 dias. (143 = 4*30 + 3*7 + 2).

Comment: Si el cálculo solo necesita semanas, no contar los meses, solo divide entre 7 para las semanas y saca el resto de la división para los días. En el ejemplo anterior 143 / 7 = 20 semanas, 143 % 7 = 3 días.

Answer (score 0):

No se si te sirva pero yo uso otro metodo para obtener la edad,
Guardo la fecha de nacimiento en la base de datos y con php calculo los dias meses y años.

Aqui te va el codigo:

```
function getEdad($fechaInicio){

if($fechaInicio<date("Y-m-j") AND $fechaInicio!=="0" AND $fechaInicio!==0){
$fecha1 = new DateTime($fechaInicio);
$fecha2 = new DateTime("today");
$fecha = $fecha1->diff($fecha2);
$tiempo = "";

//años
if($fecha->y > 0){
$tiempo .= $fecha->y;
if($fecha->y == 1){$tiempo .= " a&ntilde;o ";}else{$tiempo .= " a&ntilde;os ";}
}

//meses
if($fecha->m > 0){
$tiempo .= $fecha->m;
if($fecha->m == 1){$tiempo .= " mes ";}else{$tiempo .= " meses ";}
}

//dias
if($fecha->d > 0){
$tiempo .= $fecha->d;
if($fecha->d == 1){$tiempo .= " dia ";}else{$tiempo .= " dias ";}
}

if($fecha->y == 0 AND $decha->m == 0 AND $fecha->d == 0 && !$tiempo){

return "0 Dias";
//return "0 dias";

}
else{return $tiempo;}
}
}
```

***Nota te mando el codigo tal cual lo tengo yo, tu adaptalo a tu criterio***

Comment: Una explicación siempre es bienvenida al código que uno pública